# Homogeneous first-order Differential Equation $y' = x/y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

We have $y' = x/y$, which is a first-order homogeneous differential equation.

It can be solved by rearranging to $y\  dy = x\  dx$ and then integrating both parts which yields that $y = \pm\sqrt{x^2+c}$ .

Now if we use the substitution $y=ux\implies y'=u'x+u,$ and rewrite the differential equation as 
$$u'x+u=\frac1u$$ 
and then rearrange to 
$$\left(\frac{1}{1/u-u}\right)du=\left(\frac1x\right)dx$$ 
by integrating both parts we get that
$$-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left |u^2 -1  \right| = \ln\left |x  \right |+c \tag1$$

For $y=\pm x$ (a special solution for $c=0$) $\rightarrow u=\pm1$, and by plugging $\pm1$ into $(1)$ we get that $$\ln\left |0  \right|=\ln\left |x   \right| +c \tag2$$

What does equation $(2)$ mean? $\ln\left |0  \right|$ is undefined. Is this of any significance?

---

### Edit 1

As pointed out when rearranging from $u'x+u=\frac1u$ to $\left(\frac{1}{1/u-u}\right)du=\left(\frac1x\right)dx$, we implicitly assumed that $u\neq\pm1$. Equation $(1)$ does not hold for $u=\pm1$.

### Edit 2

Solving equation $(1)$ for u with $u\neq\pm1$, we arrive at the same family of equations but with $c\neq0$. The fact that $c$ can be zero comes from setting $u=\pm1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you rearranged your equation to get $$(\frac{1}{1/u-u})du=(1/x)dx$$ you have implicitly assumed that $u \ne \pm 1$ so $u=\pm 1$ is out of question.

Comment: So, the answer cannot be found by the second way of solving homogeneous differential equations ?

Comment: The answer could be found but one has to careful about dividing by $0$. You may take care of that case separately.

Comment: 1 and -1 are valid in the begining  for $u'x+u=1/u$ it's a valide value  though not in the final answer because we have assulmed $u \neq \pm1$

Answer (score 0):

Note that for the substitution $y=ux$
$$u'x+u=\frac 1 u \implies \int \frac {u}{1-u^2}du=\int \frac {dx}x$$

Then for $( u\neq \pm1,0)$

$$-\frac 12 \int \frac {-2u}{1-u^2}du=\int \frac {dx}x \implies 1-u^2=\frac K{x^2}$$
$$\ln(1-u^2)=-2\ln(x)+K \implies 1-u^2 =e^{-2\ln(x)+K}$$
$$\implies 1-u^2=\frac K{x^2}$$
$$\implies x^2-y^2=K$$
For the value $1,-1$ ( 0 is excluded) you can use the original equation

### $$u'x+u=\frac 1u$$

***Edit***

My post corrected some mistakes Op made in the original question...Since then the question has changed.

Comment: Are your integrations correct ?

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing this out! Plugging u=1 or u=-1 into u′x+u=1/u yields 0 = 0 which is expected, but after integrating ln|0| happens.

Comment: you are welcomed put $u=1$ in the beginning it gives a correct answer @giannisl9  or put $u=1$ in the last expression no zero at the denominator

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Isn't integral of 1/x, ln|x| for example?